# java stream реализовать метод map и filter используя только reduce

Tags: java, java-stream, map-reduce

Видел как это решается в джаваскрипте, а вот на джаве...
Руководствуясь [этой статьёй](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24308146/why-is-a-combiner-needed-for-reduce-method-that-converts-type-in-java-8), набросал так

```
public static<R,U> List<R> myMap(Stream<U> s, Function<U,R> fnctn) {
    return s.parallel().reduce(new ArrayList<R>(),
                               (List<R> list, U elem) -> list.add(fnctn.apply(elem)), 
                               (List<R> list1, List<R> list2)-> list1.addAll(list2));
}
List<String> words = Arrays.asList("word1", "word2", "word3");
System.out.println(myMap(words.stream(), s->Integer.valueOf(s.substring(s.length()-1))));
```

Чего я не понимаю?

Comment: А что тут делает `parallel`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У тебя функции, переданные в reduce, ничего не возвращают.

Можно попытаться исправить так: https://ideone.com/uS2zPY

```
/* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;
import java.util.function.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone {
  public static<R,U> List<R> myMap(Stream<U> s, Function<U,R> fnctn) {
    return s.reduce(
      new ArrayList<R>(),
      (List<R> list, U elem) -> { list.add(fnctn.apply(elem)); return list; },
      (List<R> list1, List<R> list2) -> { list1.addAll(list2); return list1; }
    );
  }

  public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
    List<String> words = Arrays.asList("word1", "word2", "word3");
    System.out.println(myMap(words.stream(), s->Integer.valueOf(s.substring(s.length()-1))));
  }
}
```

Но, судя [по описанию](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-U-java.util.function.BiFunction-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-), я на 80% уверен, что это какая-то фигня.

Comment: Спасибо. Думал содержимое функции и так подставится в возвращаемое значение. А нет. parallel тоже ни к чему кроме дублирования не приводил - убрал его.

Comment: @tacticalNuke, по-моему, этот код - фигня. Описание в документации прочитай.

Comment: @tacticalNuke, они возвращают результат вызова метода `add` и `addAll`, но они, вроде, void.

Comment: пробовал из нетбинса через контекстную менюшку найти как реализован map, но она только на интерфейс Stream прыгает/

Answer (score 2):

Судя по коду, вам лучше подойдёт метод `collect`, а не `reduce`. Плюс небольшие правки, получаем следующий работающий код функции `myMap`:

```
return s.parallel().collect(

    // 1) Лямбда, возвращающая начальный список для заполнения
    () -> new ArrayList<R>(),

    // 2) Лямбда для добавления отдельного элемента стрима в список
    (List<R> list, U elem) -> list.add(fnctn.apply(elem)),

    // 3) Лямбда объединения двух списков в один
    (List<R> list1, List<R> list2) -> list1.addAll(list2)
);
```

Однако, в Java 8 имеются уже реализованные коллекторы, в том числе для компоновки элементов потока в список. С учетом этого, лучше написать как-то так:

```
static <R, U> List<R> myMap(Stream<U> s, Function<U, R> fnctn) {
    return s.parallel().map(fnctn).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

PS: Но если вопрос именно в том, чтобы реализовать *только* через `reduce` - решение в соседнем ответе выглядит нормальным.

Comment: Именно так, в рамках учебной единицы было задание именно обойтись без всех удобств, только через `reduce`.